# Why isn't Listbox covering whole Frame in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a simple GUI with Python Tkinter, and using `Frame` as containers. When I added a `Listbox` inside the Frame, it only occupies a small space in the `Frame`, rest space remains empty. I want it to cover whole Frame. Here's the code, and the output as image:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720')
root.title("Music Player")
root.grid_rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5), weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure((0,), weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure((1,), weight=5)
root.resizable(False, False)

listframel = Frame(root, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=5)
listframel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW, rowspan=5)
listframer = Frame(root, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=5)
listframer.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NSEW, rowspan=5)

listbox = Listbox(listframel)
listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5, sticky=NSEW)
lst = list(x for x in range(100))
for i in range(len(lst)):
    listbox.insert(i+1, lst[i]+1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It is simpler to use `listbox.pack(fill='both', expand=1)` if you just want the listbox to fill the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` to all containers (root, listframel and listframer).

Comment: Typo. Should be `listframel` and `listframer` instead of `labelframe1` and `labelframer`.